# jQuery addClass on button hover to it's container div only

Tags: jquery, hover

i want to add class to div on hover button on it. when i hover this button the div will have a new class.

this HTML codes

```
<div class='post'><a class='more' href='more'>More</a></div>
<div class='post'><a class='more' href='more'>More</a></div>
<div class='post'><a class='more' href='more'>More</a></div>
<div class='post'><a class='more' href='more'>More</a></div>
<div class='post'><a class='more' href='more'>More</a></div>
<div class='post'><a class='more' href='more'>More</a></div>
```

i use this jquery code to do it

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

$( ".more" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( ".post" ).addClass( "post-hover" );
  }, function() {
    $( ".post" ).removeClass( "post-hover" );
  }
);

            });


});
```

but when i hover `a.more` this jquery code add `post-hover` to all `.post` divs. i want to do this for only one div this i hover on it's a.more link.

Comment: The reason that all the .post divs get the `post-hover` class is because your selector, `$( ".post" )` says to select all elements that have the class `post`. If you only want to change the one you are hovering, use the `$(this).parent()` selector like is shown in j08691's answer.

Comment: @Zack yes that's right but this method i used it already but add the class .post-hover to the main container div, cause all this html codes are in anther divs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To refer to the div parent, use `$(this).parent()` instead of `$(".post")`, which selects all elements with the class post.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".more").hover(
     function () {
         $(this).parent().addClass("post-hover");
     }, function () {
         $(this).parent().removeClass("post-hover");
     });
 });
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qSu43/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/2GWc2/

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $(".more").hover(function(){
       $("div.post").removeClass("post-hover");
        $(this).parent().addClass("post-hover");
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have solved my problem, according to @j08691 i should use `$(this).parent()` but this if the code like my example if i need to refer to `.post` class i should use `$(this).parents(".post")` this will add a new class for only .post class which contain the .more link and the code will be like that.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".more").hover(
     function () {
         $(this).parents(".post").addClass("post-hover");
     }, function () {
         $(this).parents(".post").removeClass("post-hover");
     });
 });
```

Comment: You don't need to refer to `.post` because `.parent()` refers to ONLY the direct parent of the `.more` class, which can only be the specific `div` with `post` class. Using `.parents()` will require you to pass in `.post` as it search back over all ancestors of the current object. This is not required in your case so long as the structure of the html is as you describe. Just getting `.parent()` will suffice and therefore I'd advise marking j08691's answer as correct.

Comment: Yes @j08691's answer is the acceptable answer for the example i give above but my answer if there is divs inside divs in this case `.parents()` needed to do this thank you.

Comment: If you have a different question then ask a different question.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to change the text color of the button when mouse hovers over it. I've tried above scripts but didn't work. However, I made it work this way.

HTML code

```
<div> 
<button class="buttonClass"> Submit </button> 
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
$(document).on("mouseover",".buttonClass", function(){
    $(this).addClass("name_of_class").mouseleave( function(){ $(this).removeClass("name_of_class"); });
});
```

CSS code

```
.name_of_class {
    background:red;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mandroid/k6eqdfxx/1/)